# NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create undefined method `confirmation_sent_at=' for #<User:0x007fd83f5ccb68>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm new to Rails. I'm using Devise to add authentication and an email confirmation upon signup. When I run the code on my local I get the error message in the title. I've reviewed similar posts and tried running `rake db:reset` and restarting the server.

I've added `:confirmable` to `models/user.rb`

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
end`

The error message highlights this block of code and specifically calls out the line of code beginning with `match ?` as line 433

`else
   match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
   match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
 end
end`

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 327ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `confirmation_sent_at=' for #   <User:0x007fd21e2ebce0>):
 activemodel (4.2.3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
 devise (3.5.2) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:240:in `generate_confirmation_token'
 activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:430:in `block in make_lambda'
 activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:143:in `call'
```

I appreciate any help!

---

**Added migration file**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :name
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_tokention_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the migration where you added confirmations?

Comment: There is a typo in your migration - shouldn't `confirmation_tokention_sent_at` be `confirmation_sent_at` ?

Comment: hmm.. logically that makes sense to me. I will say that all I did was uncomment these four lines of code for `:confirmable`. I tried `t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at` and still receive the same error.

Comment: @leo I am facing exactly similar problem can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

@Wand Maker was correct. The code should reflect `confirmation_sent_at` instead of `confirmation_tokention_sent_at`.

The additional step I had to take was to remove my `schema.rb` file, run `rake db:reset` and then `rake db:migrate` to create the updated (and correct) `schema.rb`.